# Cypress how to close window print dialog

Tags: javascript, windows, printing, cypress

I am looking to perform action on print window using cypress.

Manually when I click on the print button I get the print window like Image 1.
But when I run the same script in cypress test runner, I get the print windows as in Image 2.

I am aware that action on such window can be done using a stub. But I cant even inspect print window I get in test runner i.e. Image 2. so what shall be the locator of cancel button ??

```
let printStub
          cy.window().then(win => {
                printStub = cy.stub(win, 'print')
                cy.get(HOW DO I GET THE LOCATOR).click().then(()=>{
                    expect(win.print).to.be.called
                })
            })
```

**Image 1:**
[image]

**Image 2:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what causes the difference in the two print windows, but tecnically you don't need to test the actually printing part, just that `window.print` has been called.

If you agree, then follow this example [Replace a method with a function](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/stub#Replace-a-method-with-a-function), adding a dummy function as 3rd parameter to the stub.

```js
let printCalled = false
cy.stub(cy.state('window'), 'print', () => {
  printCalled = true
})

cy.get('the-print-button-selector').click()  // app calls window.print
  .should(() => expect(printCalled).to.eq(true))
```

or just assert the call happened

```js
const stub = cy.stub(cy.state('window'), 'print', () => {})  // replace print with do-nothing fn

cy.get('the-print-button-selector').click()  // app calls window.print
  .should(() => expect(stub).to.be.called)
```

Comment: i understood the method but the click function opens the window shown in "image 2" and the stub returns false saying that window named "print" was not called. Please help!!

Comment: It works ok for me, so the only explanation I can think of is that the app doesn't call `window.print` but something else. Can you check in the source code?